# Assign string to QLineEdit with PySide/PyQt

Tags: python, qt, pyside

I'm having a little bit of trouble assigning values to a QLineEdit. I've read the documentation and feel that the QLineEdit.SetText() command will be used at some point.

I've used Qt Designer to design a GUI for my software. On the main window (MainWindow.py, with an accompanying ui_MainWindow.py setup file), I have a LineEdit (lineEditScanBarcode) which has strong focus. I've managed to pull input from that LineEdit pretty well. What I'd like to do is this:

If the input in LineEditScanBarcode = x, then assign the name 'John Smith' to a secondary QLineEdit (lineEditUser) which has a zero focus policy. This is what I have so far:

```
def ScanBarcode(self):
    barcode = self.lineEditScanBarcode.text()
    self.lineEditScanBarcode.clear()
    if barcode == '12345':
        print("Welcome John")
        self.lineEditUser.setText() = 'John'
    else: print("Sorry, user not recognised.")
```

Upon running this, I get the following error:

```
Syntax Error: can't assign to function call
```

I've had a look at the above error, but I'm still unsure as to what's going on here. I still have no idea to open one window on top of another (this software package will have about 10 windows), but that's another story!

Is my logic here on track? I've never used Qt before, so my understanding of the intricacies involved is lacking to say the least.

Any input would be great!

Comment: Your error message says `can't assign to function call`. And this is what you're doing here: `self.lineEditUser.setText() = 'John'`. I guess `self.lineEditUser.setText('John')` is what you meant.

Comment: @zero323 Thank you very much for the clarification, that makes perfect sense now, and will no doubt help with future understanding of this class. Thanks!

Comment: python doesn't accept `self.lineEditUser.setText() =  'John'self.lineEditUser.setText() = 'John'` , Because you assigned a value to function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the comment states, the error is on this line:

```
self.lineEditUser.setText() = 'John'
```

You are attempting to assign the value `'John'` to that functioncall (as the error states). If you review the documentation for [QLineEdit in PyQT](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qlineedit.html#setText), you'll see that `QLineEdit.setText()` requires a string to be passed to it.

So, what you need to do instead is pass the value `'John'` to the function like so:

```
self.lineEditUser.setText('John')
```

On another note your idea that your

> software package will have about 10 windows

is definitely something that you want to reexamine. More windows, especially when undocked and floating independently will no doubt cause usability issues. I'd strongly recommend sharing your ideas over at [UserExperience.SE](https://ux.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Awesome answer, thank you very much! This makes perfect sense now.